# Chaining decorators result is confusing me

Tags: python, decorator

```
def decor1(func):
    def inner():
        x = func()
        return x * x
    return inner
 
def decor(func):
    def inner():
        x = func()
        return 2 * x
    return inner
 
@decor1
@decor
def num():
    return 10
 
print(num())
```

Can someone explain why the result is 400?
Is it because inner is being returned twice?
I'm learning chaining decorators but it's a bit confusing at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `num` function returns `10`, which is then passed to `decor` (one level higher) in variable `x` (note that `func()` refers to `num()`, hence it returns `10`). `x` is multiplied by 2, yielding `20`. The `20` is passed to `decor1` (another level higher) in variable `x` and is multiplied by itself, so `20` times `20` yields `400`.

Answer (score 2):

The first decorator applied is `@decor`, so at this stage your `num` function will return `2*10`.
Then `@decor1` is applied so in the end `num` returns `(2*10)*(2*10)` which is 400.